# How to add firebase-admin to my android project?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

Why when I try to add firebase-admin into my android project, the gradle tells me that "Version 5.5.0 is lower than the minimum version (9.0.0) required for google-services plugin" But version 5.5.0 of firebase-admin it's latest at this moment. WTH?

**build.gradle**

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.GrenderG:Toasty:1.2.5'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'
    compile group: 'com.google.firebase', name: 'firebase-admin', version: '5.5.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.6.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

firebase-admin is not intended for use in Android apps.  It's for accessing Firebase services from servers your control.

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#prerequisites) regarding prequisites:

> - **Make sure that you have a server app.**
> - Make sure that your server runs the following depending on which Admin SDK that you use:
>
>   - Admin Node.js SDK — Node.js 8.13.0+
>   - Admin Java SDK — Java 7+ (recommend Java 8+)
>   - Java 7 support is deprecated.
>   - Admin Python SDK — Python 3.5+
>   - Admin Go SDK — Go 1.9+
>       Admin .NET SDK — .NET Framework 4.5+ or .Net Core 1.5+

The google-services plugin is giving you that warning because it thinks every maven target with group "com.google.firebase" is actually a Firebase Android client SDK, which all must be the same version in your app.

Comment: Using admin operations android side is not recommended. If you want to use the admin SDK, use it from a server you control, and have your Android app communicate with that if needed.

In Fact, with the Admin SDK, you can read and write Realtime Database data with full admin privileges so you have to use it on trusted devices only (such as a server you control). If you embed the
 Firebase Admin SDK into an public Android app, you will allow all of your users full access to your entire Firebase project. This is not recommended.