# Firebase Admin SDK in Android App

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I have developed my client side application using Android studio and it went well. 
But I have an issue, I want to have an Android App with Administrator Privileges. On my Client Side I have used FirebaseFirestore but on Admin SDK documents I did not see this option for FirebaseFirestore. And I can't find classes for FirebaseFirestore or references instead I found Cloud Firestore. Do I have to go back to FirebaseDatabase in my Client Side to implement this in Admin Side?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add firebase-admin to my android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581505/how-to-add-firebase-admin-to-my-android-project)

Comment: You can't use the Java Admin SDK in an Android app.  Instead, look into using Cloud Functions for Firebase to run code with the Node Admin SDK, triggered by your Android app. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Admin does support [Firestore,](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) the Admin API just provide the Admin app to have full privileges (as you mentioned), it will just work the same way like your client app but instead of using User credential, you just have to replace it with the service account.

[Firebase Admin Setup](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start)